# How to enable linting after ignore_for_file in the same file

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

```dart
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
class Class1 {
  final _count_me = 0;
  final _count2_1 = 0;

  Class1() {
    _count_me + _count2_1;
  }
}

// ignore_for_file: -non_constant_identifier_names
class Class2 {
  final count_me = 0; // lint error with non_constant_identifier_names
  final _count2 = 0; 
  Class2() {
    count_me + _count2;
  }
}
```

I've tried `// ignore_for_file: -non_constant_identifier_names` but it's not working.
I want disable `non_constant_identifier_names` on `Class1`, but enable it on `Class2`.
`-` is not working in Android Studio, `Class2.count_me` still no lint warning.

Answer (score 2):

`// ignore_for_file:` will make the specified linter rule being ignored in the whole file, even if this comment is not on the top of the file (so it will make the code before and after this line ignore the rule).

You should use `// ignore:` instead. This will ignore a linter rule only for the line below it.

```dart
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
class Class1 {
  final _count_me = 0;
  final _count2_1 = 0;

  Class1() {
    _count_me + _count2_1;
  }
}

class Class2 {
  final count_me = 0; // lint error with non_constant_identifier_names
  final _count2 = 0; 
  Class2() {
    count_me + _count2;
  }
}
```

---

See also:

- [Suppressing diagnostics for a file](https://dart.dev/tools/analysis#suppressing-diagnostics-for-a-file)
- [Suppressing diagnostics for a line of code](https://dart.dev/tools/analysis#suppressing-diagnostics-for-a-line-of-code)

Comment: I'm new to Dart, so linter does not support ignore linter rule in code block yet? like C# `#pragma`

Comment: From the docs link I referred above, I think these two are the only options

Comment: You could maybe make the two classes in separate files and make use of `part` and `part of`